# How to fix return of NULL for scraping data using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I'm having difficulty getting the data I need from a website. I'm new to data scraping and I'm unsure on how to find the elements of a website. I need data from 2011-2022, but I am only getting the data for 2020, 2021, and 2022. All of the other years have NULL. Here is my code:

```
# vector of years
years <- c(rep(2011:2022, by = 1))

# empty vector to store urls
urls <- c()

# create full urls for each year
for (i in 1:12) {
  urls[i] <- paste0("https://www.spotrac.com/nhl/cap/", years[i], "/")
}

# empty list to store payroll tables
payrolls <- list()

# read in url and create a table for each year
for (i in 1:length(urls)) {
  temp <- read_html(urls[i])
  temp2 <- temp %>% html_nodes("table")
  payrolls[i] <- temp2 %>% html_table
}
```

[Payroll Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tClQ2.png)

The image attached is the output. The last three elements of the list are exactly what I want in the format I want, but I just can't figure out the other years.

My assumption is the the type of node for years that aren't returning anything is different than "table", and I tried to use the Selector Gadget to extract the type of node but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: did you try to manually navigate to https://www.spotrac.com/nhl/cap/2019?
It returns a "log for premium data" login wall.

Comment: Yes, I have a subscription to the website so I have full access.

Comment: rvest does not emulate a browser, it simply scrape the html response, so it cannot log in as you log in a browser. It has basic session management with rvest::session, also you have some methods for http in httr package. 
It is better to use `RSelenium` if the login process is to messy.

Comment: I got it to work using rvest::session, thank you.

Comment: Without being able to access the url due to the paywall, it is very difficult to tell.
A quick and dirty way to test your assumption is to print the results of `temp %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()` in each iteration of the loop. If you get tables, then the css works. If not, you need to find the right css or xpath path.